# ajax to get value one result on php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This will return only one row how to simply pass that row to ajax call.
below code passing data , but when i print it in loop it print unlimited times.

AJAX::

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'userLoginCheckforRetrieve.php',
  data: {
  },
   success:function(data)   { 
   alert('outside loop is '+data);
 for(var i=0; i < data.length ; i++){
    alert('loop date is '+data[i].name);
    }
}
});
```

PHP ::

```
$sel_query= "SELECT image_name FROM save_designs WHERE user_name='{$username}'";
    $sel_result = mysql_query($sel_query);

    $data = array();
    while($item = mysql_fetch_object($sel_result))
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'name' => $item->image_name                
            );
        }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: could you please post a small snippet of what `alert('outside loop is '+data);` is like ? or just content of `data.length`

Comment: use `console.log` instead of alert, and use `$.get` for getting data. Plus, drop old `mysql_*` functions for `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: @monnwave99 - why $.get ? is there a specific reason? he is using an ajax call with a POST type.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid because `GET` is the verb for getting data [by definition].

Comment: @monnwave99 - `$.get()` is just a shortcut for an `$.ajax()` call of type "GET". - by definition, if you are trying to simplify the request the correct method should be `$.post()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to parse a string as JSON. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
 url: 'userLoginCheckforRetrieve.php',
 data: {}, //Pass data here
 success:function(data)   { 
     var obj = JSON.parse(data); // parse a string as JSON
    alert('outside loop is '+data);
    for(var i=0; i < obj.length ; i++){
      alert('loop date is '+obj[i].name);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a JSON parser to convert it...

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'userLoginCheckforRetrieve.php',
       data: {},
       success:function(data)   { 
         data = $.parseJSON(data);
         for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
         alert('loop date is '+data[i].name);
       }}
});
```

The json returned is a string so by parsing it you will create an object that contain
 all the json string elements and their values.

Note: make sure you php files has no warnings that are printed and that the returned page is a clean JSON string => {  ....  }

have Fun!